# Auto rotation for 1 tab out of 5

Tags: iphone, tabs, rotation

I have 5 tabs in my app and one needs to be able to autorotate. So far I have been able to get all 5 tabs to rotate using:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}
```

However I only need 1 to rotate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the active tab using myTabBarController.selectedIndex or myTabBarController.selectedViewController. Return YES or NO based on which tab is active.

Beware though: what happens if you rotate the device in a non-rotating tab (i.e. nothing happens), then go to your rotating tab? My guess is that it will be in its previous, unrotated state, as it never received any messages concerning rotation.